# JavaScript data object and render

Tags: javascript

heres my code

```
  var readAll = function () {
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                    "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('PhoneBook')/items/" +
                    "?$select=Id, Title, pb_FirstName, pb_PhoneNumber" +
                    "&$orderby=Title,pb_FirstName, pb_PhoneNumber",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            }
        );
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    readAll();
});

data = {
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "b4d773a6-f31e-442d-8974-38c535d491d6",
                "uri": "mysite:6555",
                "etag": "\"1\"",
                "type": "SP.Data.LST_x005f_PhoneBookListItem"
            },
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "name11",
            "pb_FirstName": "name",
            "pb_PhoneNumber": "1234",
            "ID": 1
        }]
    }
}

function readList(data) {

    var html = [];
    html.push("<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th>" +
              "<th>Last Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr></table></thead>");

    data = data.d.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        html.push("<tr><td>");
        html.push(results[i].ID);
        html.push("</td><td>");
        html.push(results[i].Title);
        html.push("</td><td>");
        html.push(results[i].pb_FirstName);
        html.push("</td><td>");
        html.push(results[i].pb_PhoneNumber);
        html.push("</td><tr>");
    }

    html.push("</table>"`enter code here`);
    $('.table').html(html.join(''));
}
```

so i get an in the console a json array with the data. im trying to bring the data in my html table. but i dont know how. so i need to bring my data object and render it in the right html
hope u can help me

Comment: Please don't do things like `html.push(results[i].Title);` without first making sure you're not susceptible to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).  If you're not, document why not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
console.log(data);
```

with the strangely named

```
readList(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $.get for get data and handlebars for render html with data, its easy.
[// Link handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

```
var template = "<table>\
    <thead>\
        <tr>\
            <th>ID</th>\
            <th>Title</th>\
            <th>First Name</th>\
            <th>Phone</th>\
        </tr>\
    </thead>\
    <tbody>\
    {{#objects}}\
    <tr>\
        <td>{{ Id }}</td>\
        <td>{{ Title }}</td>\
        <td>{{ pb_FirstName }}</td>\
        <td>{{ pb_PhoneNumber }}</td>\
    </tr>\
    {{/objects}}\
    </tbody>\
</table>";

$.get('someurl')
.success(function(response){
    //here render data to html
    // We can use Handlebars, is a engine of templates.
    $("#box").html(Handlebars.compile(template)({'objects' : response['d']['results']}));
})
.error(function(err){
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: how should i render the data to html? can you make an example please?